# Windows DHCP MAC-Range to Scope allocation

Tags: windows, networking, virtualization, virtual-machines, dhcp

I wonder if there is any options to map a specific Range of MAC addresses to a specific DHCP address scope.

The thing is, I want a specific scope for address allocation to bridged Virtual Machines (Hyper-V , VMWare).

eg :

```
MAC="0015d5*" => Scope="192.168.254.0/24"
```

Comment: Background: I recently encountered the feature which allows to whitelist / blacklist MAC addresses for Windows DHCP server (with the possibility to use wildcards). This is why I think maybe that feature exists

Answer (score 0):

Windows DHCP Server (2012) supports policies.

See:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh831538.aspx

Basically, you create a policy, establish an IP range, and assign MAC addresses to the policy.

Update:
The closest thing that Windows server DHCP Policies would allow, as far as "MAC wildcarding" goes is probably specifying a Policy based on a vendor class. Keeping in mind part of the MAC defines a manufacturer for example. So I suppose if your DHCP scope could use an "obscure vendor" of your choice, you could assign MAC addresses within the vendor. Often the MAC for a specific product starts off with the same set of characters. Not a precise fix, but it might be a work-around.